# Make it clear that advertisements are "official" and not spam or part of the answer

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, advertising

Today I saw this, and on first glance it looked as if the advertisement was part of the answer:

> [image: inline advertisement between answers]

On first glance it's not trivial to spot it's not part of the answer, and the small Like/Dislike icons that used to appear in the past have been removed at some point. If I find it non trivial to spot, I am pretty sure many others are getting really confused about it, and think it's some kind of spam, especially when posted on non-SO sites.

Can something be added to the advertisement box to make it clear it's an advertisement? One way would be like other ad hosts are doing, by adding small icons always visible on top:

[image: advertisement with icons]

The "i" icon would show information about the ad and why we see it, the "x" icon is probably not relevant for Stack Exchange so can be removed, one icon would be enough to know it's OK.

Another advantage is having the ability to explain how that specific ad is collecting information about us (e.g. cookies), if at all, which would comply with the recent GDPR rules.

Comment: I'm currently spec'ing out pretty much this exact feature (a way to flag or provide feedback for ads). I've got a couple other projects I'm juggling atm, so it might be a little bit before I get to it, but it's high on my priority list.

Comment: @rossipedia It used to be possible a long time ago to give feedback for ads; when was this changed? Was it changed when SE changed its ad network from Adzerk to Google AdSense?

Comment: Yes, that was a feature exclusive to Adzerk, which we lost when we moved to Google DFP

Comment: @Sonic [not even a year ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301524/all-sites-will-be-switching-ad-servers-on-october-1), won't call it "long time", unless you live by the second. :-)